# Pressurized Plasma: Pneumatic, and Transformer system

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, plasma-physics

I am trying to create an apparatus that acts as a pneumatic system, and a transformer simultaneously. Would such a device work? To set it up I would create a copper pipe pneumatic system that carried within it an ionized gas (neon plasma probably). If I wrapped the copper pipe with a ferrite magnet and then put it in a transformer would it generate a current/voltage in the "secondary" winding?

Comment: This sounds problematic. How do you create a durable plasma in a copper pipe? How do you expect ephemeral plasma to exert a significant amount of pressure? And, why are you seeking this?

Comment: @DanielGriscom I was planning on putting on a spark plug inside the copper pipping to constantly ionize the gas.

Comment: ... to what end? And, the copper pipe will probably quench the plasma before traveling more than a few diameters down the pipe.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Sorry for responding late, but what do you mean by quench?

Comment: Plasma isn't stable, especially in the presence of a cold conductor (the copper). So, the electrons and nuclei will rejoin, and all you'll have is (hot) air.